# MAC's "say" command to MP3

Tags: macos, shell, ffmpeg, mp3

I want to read a very long text with the SAY mac's command (`say -f file.txt`), and to record the output to `file.mp3`. I thought about using ffmpeg to record all of it, but then i'll need to wait for all the reading process to complete..

I don't really need to listen to it, so if there is a way to directly have an `mp3` file just by hitting enter, it would be great..

There is also this project [txt2mp3mac](https://code.google.com/p/txt2mp3mac/) but i can't use it in a shell script..

Thanks..

Comment: Why can't you use `txt2mp3mac` in a shell script?

Comment: there is no cli for this program!

Comment: It appears to be an open-source applecsript app, it should be easy to modify, I'd think.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I'm not on a Mac right now, so I can't test, but [this page](http://iamcam.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/tell-your-mac-to-say-anything-and-record-it/) suggests you can do

```
say -f script.txt -o greetings.aiff
```

to load what should be said from `script.txt` and save the audio output as `greetings.aiff`. You can then convert it to mp3 using [`lame`](http://lame.sourceforge.net/index.php) with

```
lame -m m greetings.aiff greetings.mp3
```

Definitely try the [different voices](https://web.archive.org/web/20121107015750/http://gohgarry.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/fun-with-mac-say-command/). :D

Comment: Thanks!  For Homebrew users that need Lame: `brew install lame`

Comment: Starting in MacOS X 10.6, say supports file formats other than AIFF