# Is there a way to programmatically capture audio output of VoiceOver reading a web page?

Tags: macos, accessibility, voiceover

Suppose I wanted to have Apple VoiceOver read out the contents of a webpage running in a browser, including responses to interactions, and ultimately output the result as audio.

For example, for a web page with HTML such as the following:

`<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </body>
    </html>`

I want to write an audio stream, say, in a Wave file, in which VoiceOver says something like:

> Name, edit text. You are currently on a text field inside of web content... etc...

Would this be possible programmatically? E.g. by calling some API method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MAC's "say" command to MP3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501663/macs-say-command-to-mp3)

Comment: I wouldn't say so because that question is just about converting a webpage to spoken word, whereas I want to fully simulate the voice-over experience, including calling out input controls, etc. I've updated the question text to reflect this.